# Android core vitals Overall (average across devices) vs Per phone model

Tags: android, google-play, android-vitals

In Android core vitals of Google play console we get two values
1)Overall (average across devices)
2)Per phone model
Here what I understand the first metrics is that is consider all Android devices in market. But what about per phone model ? Which phone model they are referring ?

I have gone through official doc and other AI tools as well but didn't find answer. Please explain these terms.